# How to get email member on simple_form from wallet model? [complicated relation]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have problem. I'm trying to get an email member from wallet_id which that relation not direct to member instead to investor account first like the sample model below.

member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :investor_account, dependent: :destroy
end
```

investor_account.rb

```
class InvestorAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :wallets, dependent: :destroy
end
```

wallet.rb

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :investor_account
end
```

top_up.rb

```
belongs_to :wallet
```

/top_ups/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for [:transaction, @top_up] do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.input :wallet_id, collection: @wallet, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, include_blank: "Select..."
  .form-group
    = f.input :amount, input_html: { min: 0, value: 0 }
```

/controllers/top_ups_controller.rb

```
def new
  @top_up = TopUp.new
  @wallet = Wallet.joins(:investor_account).where(investor_accounts: {approval_status: 'approved'})
end
```

The data on "f.input :wallet_id ...." was showed up, but it is not as email of the member instead it showing `#<Wallet:0x007fd6d795e808>` on all wallet dropdown, previously I also write code like below.

```
= f.input :wallet_id, collection: @wallet, :id, :email, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, include_blank: "Select..."
```

But it throwing problem the email not found. My question was how do I pass the member on that `@wallet = ...` variable to get email member showing on my form? Is there better way to get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label_method` and `value_method` params ([docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections)):

```
= f.input :wallet_id, collection: @wallet, value_method: :id, label_method: :email, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, include_blank: "Select..."
```

Also if you need only id and email, there is no need to fetch all the other data from the DB, you can use [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck):

```
# controller
def new
  @top_up = TopUp.new
  @wallet = Wallet.joins(:investor_account).where(investor_accounts: {approval_status: 'approved'}).pluck(:id, :email)
end

# form
= f.input :wallet_id, collection: @wallet, value_method: :first, label_method: :last, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, include_blank: "Select..."
```

Comment: I use .pluck(:id, :email) it shown the email doesn't exist on wallets, the email in here was on members table. Is that another way to passing the email from members table on wallet?

Comment: which model has an email field?

Comment: Member model has an email field